# Getting spesific data from three models in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am starting working with django and i want get specific data from three related  models.
my models are

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    ...

class Certification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution)
    certification = models.ForeignKey(Certification)
```

in my html page i want display the courses offered by a particular institution ordered by certification. like this

```
name of a particular institution I 
    certification 1
         list courses that offer certification 1
    certification 2
         list courses that offer certification 2
    ...
```

my current template is

```
{{institution.name}}
{% for certification in preselected_certifications %}
    <h1> {{ certification.name }} </h1>
    <ul>
          {% for course in courses %}
            <li>{{ course.name }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

my view

```
def detail(request, slug):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {'slug_requested': slug}
    try:
      institution = Institution.objects.get(slug=slug)
      courses = Course.objects.filter(etablissement=etablissement)

      context_dict['courses'] = courses
      context_dict['institution'] = institution

    except Institution.DoesNotExist:
      pass

    return render_to_response('institutition/details.html', context_dict, context)
```

my question is how define "preselected_certifications" so it contains only certifications offered by all courses in the selected institution, but without repeating any certification

Comment: But you aren't defining anything called `preselected_certifications`.

Comment: Where does the `etablissement` come from, that you're using to filter `Courses`? The provided code seems incomplete. Furthermore you don't assign preselected_certification while rendering your template.

Comment: thats my problem ! how to define preselected_certifications !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question:

> how define "preselected_certifications" so it contains only certifications offered by all courses in the selected institution, but without repeating any certification

I don't know exactly how you want to represent this information (meaning, which attributes you want available), but think you want something like the following:

```
def detail(request, slug):
   ...
   institution = Institution.objects.get(slug=slug)

   # `select_related` not strictly necessary
   courses = institution.course_set.all().select_related('certification')

   context_dict['courses'] = courses
   context_dict['institution'] = institution
```

Now, each `course` object will have access to its `certification` relation and you *could* iterate through them to display the unique ones.

However, if you want to ensure from the outset these `certification`s are unique, one way to do that is with another query:

```
   institution = Institution.objects.get(slug=slug)
   courses = institution.course_set.select_related('certification')
   certification_ids = courses.values_list('certification_id', flat=True).distinct()
   preselect_certifications = Certification.objects.filter(id__in=certification_ids)
```

That last query will get you the unique certifications for a particular institution.

It seems like `Certification` should potentially have a relationship to `Institution`, though, no?

Comment: yeah thanks a lot, now i use in my template the following code

{% for certification in preselect_certifications %}
   {{certification.name}} 
   {% for course in courses %}
      <ul>
      {% if certification = course.certification %}
         <li>{{ course.name }}</li>
      {% endif %}
      </ul>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
it works perfectly, but is there another way to avoid using

{% if certification = course.certification %}
?

thanks again

Comment: Yeah, for each certification just iterate through its `course_set`.

Comment: using ur code suggestion, if i iterate through course_set for each certification, i ll get courses that are not in the specified instituiton

Comment: i think i shoud test for each iteration that certification.institution = INSTITUTION. it works but is it optimal ?

Answer (score 0):

yeah thanks a lot, now i use in my template the following code

```
{% for certification in preselect_certifications %}
   {{certification.name}} 
   {% for course in courses %}
      <ul>
      {% if certification = course.certification %}
         <li>{{ course.name }}</li>
      {% endif %}
      </ul>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

it works perfectly, but is there another way to avoid using

```
{% if certification = course.certification %}
```

?

thanks again